# Laravel 5 controller Routing does not work

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am familiar with Laravel 4 routes, but I am experiencing some problem with Laravel 5.

I code route.php as:

```
     Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
```

and my `HomeController.php` is the following:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('index');
    }
}
```

The output page displays as:

```
 Whoops,looks like something went wrong.
```

The Route annotation file seems to be perfect.

The same case occurs for folder routing too!!

Please help me out.

Comment: go to .envexample file and change it to .env and make sure that the debug is set to true so that you can actually see the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should follow the instructions from James Njuguna in a comment to your question. Withoug debugging we can only guess whats going wrong.

In your case, most likely your error is, that the line

```
return View::make('index');
```

is causing an exception, because class App\Http\Controllers\View is not found. In this file a namespace is used, so you have to reference the root namespace like:

```
return \View::make('index');
```

OR you use a helper function

```
return view('index');
```

This function is documentated at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#miscellaneous

If that's still failing... maybe you don't have an index.php or index.blade.php in your resources/views  folder.

Answer (score 0):

All, what @shock_gone_wild and @JamesNjuguna said is true.  The reason of an error occurring is that you do not use namespaces when you call `View`.

For testing you can simply return text from a controller like this:

```
public function index()
{
    return 'test'
}
```

and when it returns a result you can see what was the reason for the error and than you can change it with view global function, like @JamesNjuguna said.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
```

In laravel 5 the view class is not illuminated using a capital letter at the beginning